# Can I use bindings with SL5 RC Markup Extensions?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

Can I use bindings with SL5 RC Markup Extensions?

Here's my XAML:

```
...
    <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                   <local:LengtherMarkupExtension Test="{Binding ElementName='MyTextBox', Path='Text'}" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
...
```

And the ME:

```
public class LengtherMarkupExtension: FrameworkElement,
        IMarkupExtension<string>
    {
        public LengtherMarkupExtension()
        {
            //this.DataContext = this;
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(LengtherMarkupExtension),
                new PropertyMetadata("DefaultValue",
                    (o, e) => 
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                    }));


        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)this.GetValue(LengtherMarkupExtension.TestProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(LengtherMarkupExtension.TestProperty, value); }
        }


        public string ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this.Test.Length.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Test property of my ME doesn't get set via binding no matter what, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: markup extention gets executed during xaml parsing and bindings are set in run time, so those two can never meet :(

Comment: Thanks, Denis, could post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup extensions get called by XAML parser during pasring process and at that time bindings can not be resolved. Based on your example it looks like you may want to return binding instead.